# If $D_2f = 0$, how can i show that $f(x,y_1) = f(x,y_2) \forall y_1,y_2$

Tags: real-analysis

$f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$
If $D_2f = 0$, how can i show that $f(x,y_1) = f(x,y_2) \forall y_1,y_2$

I'm having troubles showing this without integrating. Using the deifnition of the limit I have found that $\forall \epsilon > 0 $ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|h|< \delta$ imples $|f(x,y+h) - f(x,y)| < \epsilon |h|$ but I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: Why not integrate?

Answer (score 3):

The mean value theorem shows that for any $y_1,y_2$ there exists some $\xi \in (y_1,y_2)$ such that $f(x,y_1) = f(x,y_2) + {\partial f(x,\xi) \over \partial y} (y_1-y_2)$.

Comment: I don't know if the function is continuous

Comment: The function $t \mapsto f(x,t)$ is differentiable, so it must be continuous. However, continuity as such is irrelevant here. Are you familiar with the mean value theorem?

Comment: Note that the $x$ variable is irrelevant to the problem in that you fix $x$.

Comment: yes and it requires continuity

Comment: One more time. Fix $x$. Then the function $\phi(y) = f(x,y)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. Hence it is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. Since the derivative is zero and the domain connected, the function $\phi$ is constant. Hence $f(x,y_1) = f(x,y_2)$ for all $x,y_1,y_2$.

Comment: Continuity in the $x$ variable is irrelevant and not necessary, for example the function $f(x,y) = 1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$ satisfies the hypotheses.